# Filter strings that don't follow regex pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to filter strings from a pandas dataframe which don't follow a certain pattern. But I only get a empty Dataframe

My Code

```
l = ['Dubai', 'St. Petersburg', 'Aachen', '21323', '123134', 'Klaus@facebook.com']
l = pd.DataFrame(l)

pattern = re.compile("([A-Z])\w+|(\w[A-Z\u00E4-\u02AF])\w+", re.UNICODE)
df = l.filter(regex=pattern)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Expected Output:

```
                0
0           Dubai
1  St. Petersburg
2          Aachen
3            None
4            None
5            None
```

Comment: Not sure about Pandas, but "St. Petersburg" doesn't match your RegEx. You need to allow for "\." and "\s"/" " for that to be included.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm sorry to ask but I'm not that sophisticated with regex and tried to test around with your recommendation but couldn't make it could you help me to where insert those lines?

Comment: I recommend using regex101.com for all your regex-needs. (Just make sure to use Python Flavor)
https://regex101.com/r/8c0Ij3/1

Honestly - I am not sure what your RegEx is 'supposed' to find. What did you want it to do?

Comment: [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) doesn't do what you are expecting it to, it filters dataframe base labels of the index. From docs: ***Note that this routine does not filter a dataframe on its contents. The filter is applied to the labels of the index.***

Comment: @tst yes I'm using regex101.com I just wanted to filter out the city names and delete any numbers, emails or websites anything which is not a String starting with Capital letter

Comment: @ch3ster is there any other pd function that works better? It was recommended me here in some post to use pd.filter

Comment: @Changer how about this? https://regex101.com/r/N4dNaH/3

You might need to add more characters to the first set [A-Z], as it does not include any non-ASCII characters, like Ö or Ø

Answer (score 0):

The `df.filter()` method filters based on the name of rows/columns, not their content; as stated in the documentation: “Note that this routine does not filter a data frame on its contents. The filter is applied to the labels of the index.”

To do what you want you can define a function like this that does the pattern matching:

```
import numpy as np
import re

def like(x, pattern):
    r = re.compile(pattern)
    vlike = np.vectorize(lambda val: bool(r.fullmatch(val)))
    return vlike(x)
```

And then pass it to `.loc[]`:

```
df = df.loc[like(df['column_name'], pattern), :]
```

Now, df should contain only the rows where the column 'column_name' matches the given pattern.

You can see an example in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-equivalent-of-10-useful-sql-queries-f79428e60bd9#8392).

Comment: thanks for your feedback, but since I wanted the non matching values return to None I used boolean indexing which seems way smover solution here ```pattern = re.compile("^([a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]+(?:(\. )|-| |'))*[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]*$", re.IGNORECASE)
l[l.str.match(pattern)==False]= None```